# Python: extracting numbers from string using regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm having a string and trying to find all numbers such as 1, -1.5, .5, etc. I already found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703390/how-to-extract-a-floating-number-from-a-string-in-python) with very helpful answers. The only problem I have is that all these solution seem to match "too much". For example, the match "17" in "MH17". How can I extend any of the proposed solution so that a number cannot start with (or contain) a letter?

Comment: Can you provide valid and invalid cases of matching and what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrite the original regex: fix +/- bug and exclude the case starting with letter

```
(?<=\s)[+-]?\d+(?:.\d)?\d*
```

Also please find [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/eI4oM4/1)

Comment: +1, but you can simplify it a bit with `(?<=\s)[+-]?\d+(?:.\d+)?`

Comment: Shouldn't you escape the dot?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Thank you very much for the improvement.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works pretty perfect for my needs!