# extracting only float values out of a list in python

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
rateLimit[0] =  ((Decimal('3445'),(Decimal('65655'),(Decimal('3765'))
```

I only need the numbers : 3445 , 65655 , 3765

Is there a way out other that rstrip and lstrip.

Currently I am doing :

```
myStr = str(rateLimit[0])

mystr = myStr.lstrip("(Decimal('")

mystr = mystr.rstrip("'),)")
```

Is there a more Pythonic way to do so?

Comment: Try `[digit for digit in rateLimit[0] : if digit.isdigit()]`.

Comment: this doesnt work as the correct float values are not returned

Comment: Use regular expression check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703390/how-to-extract-a-floating-number-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: This line - `rateLimit[0] =  ((Decimal('3445'),(Decimal('65655'),(Decimal('3765'))` is missing  some parenthesis. Can you correct it?

Comment: its just an ex..basically ratelimit is getting values from sql table...in this form

Comment: there is a sql table where ratelimit are defined for each customer..i have connected sql through MySQLdb.connect and returning ratelimit from there