# Retrieve decimals not enclosed with whitespace

Tags: python, regex

In a string I want all the decimal numbers, i.e something like `23.45`.

However the condition is that the number should be between spaces and not like `length23.455` or `23.45is the length`.

So the decimal in the string `length 23.455`  is acceptable.

If there is a number like `23.45.34` it should be ignored, i.e neither `23.45` nor `45.34` should be displayed.

Need a regex pattern that finds all the matches in Python.

For example, consider the following string:

```
"6.5 from1.2 .34 12.34 13.44.55 12.34.55.66 11.43 12.3 12. 12.78~ fdasfdashf 66.8987"
```

I need a code like the following

```
import re
input_str = "6.5 from1.2 .34 12.34 13.44.55 12.34.55.66 11.43 12.3 12. 12.78~ fdasfdashf 66.8987"
print(re.findall(<regex>, input_str)) # replace <regex> with appropriate regex.
```

The output generated should be :

```
6.5, 12.34, 11.43, 12.3, 66.8987
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if the number is NOT preceded or followed by a non-whitespace character, you can achieve that with look-arounds `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)`. The regex to match a float with obligatory integer and decimal part is trivial: [`\d+\.\d+`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703390/how-to-extract-a-floating-number-from-a-string-in-python).

```
import re
input_str = "6.5 from1.2 .34 12.34 13.44.55 12.34.55.66 11.43 12.3 12. 12.78~ fdasfdashf 66.8987"
print(re.findall(r"(?<!\S)\d+\.\d+(?!\S)", input_str))
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/G3ILv6)

Result: `['6.5', '12.34', '11.43', '12.3', '66.8987']`

Comment: @user1939366: Please let me know if that works for you. Just drop a comment if anything is unclear.

Comment: Isn't that checking that it is not preceded or followed by a *non*-whitespace character?

Comment: The explanation is fixed. `?!`  mean NOT and `\S` means non-whitespace.