# How can I split a string with no delimiters but with fixed number of decimal places - python

Tags: python

What is the best way to split the following string into 6 float values. The number of decimal points will always be six.

```
x='  2C   6s         0.043315-143.954801 17.872676 31.277358-18.149649114.553363'
```

The output should read:

```
y=[0.043315, -143.954801, 17.872676, 31.277358, 18.149649, 114.553363]
```

Comment: So you want to throw `2C` and `6s` away?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703390/how-to-extract-a-floating-number-from-a-string-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703390/how-to-extract-a-floating-number-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Yes, I can throw away the 2C and 6S. Only interested in the floats.

Comment: I get everything but there is no rule to separate **18.149649, 114.553363**

Comment: I agree with that. I think that should be `-18.149649`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want to get `-18.149649` instead of `18.149649` since that would be consistent I suggest using a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) in combination with the [`.findall()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) as follows:

```
import re

regex = '(-?[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{6})'

x = '  2C   6s         0.043315-143.954801 17.872676 31.277358-18.149649114.553363'

out = re.findall(regex, x)

print(out)
```

Giving:

```
['0.043315', '-143.954801', '17.872676', '31.277358', '-18.149649', '114.553363']
```

*Update due to comment:*

You could replace `[0-9]` with `\d` which is equivalent since `\d` matches a digit (number) as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/cP3wO0/1).

Comment: Can `0-9` substituted by `\d` ?

Comment: @Khaleel: You're right. See the regex sandbox [here](https://regex101.com/r/cP3wO0/1)

Comment: @albert: That worked like a charm. Thank you. I have very limited experience using regex, but I will now look into them more.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

```
re.findall(r'\-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]{6}', string)
```