# How do you extract the floats from the elements in a python list?

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup4 to build a script that does financial calculations. I have successfully extracted data to a list, but only need the float numbers from the elements.

For Example:

```
Volume = soup.find_all('td', {'class':'text-success'})

print (Volume)
```

This gives me the list output of:

```
[<td class="text-success">+1.3 LTC</td>, <td class="text- success">+5.49<span class="muteds">340788</span> LTC</td>, <td class="text-success">+1.3 LTC</td>,]
```

I want it to become:

```
[1.3, 5.49, 1.3]
```

How can I do this?

Thank-you so much for reading my post I greatly appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703390/how-to-extract-a-floating-number-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: The list is obviously not a valid python list. Do you mean `["<td ...>+1.3</td>", ...]`?

Comment: @linusg not a valid python list, but this is how the `BeautifulSoup`'s `ResultSet` string representation looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the first text node inside every `td`, split it by space, get the first item and convert it to `float` via `float()` - the `+` would be handled automatically:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-success">+1.3 LTC</td>
        <td class="text-success">+5.49<span class="muteds">340788</span> LTC</td>
        <td class="text-success">+1.3 LTC</td>
    </tr>
</table>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

print([
    float(td.find(text=True).split(" ", 1)[0])
    for td in soup.find_all('td', {'class':'text-success'})
])
```

Prints `[1.3, 5.49, 1.3]`.

Note how the `find(text=True)` helps to avoid extracting the `340788` in the second `td`.

Comment: Thank-You for being so awesome. This works very well!

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("\d+\.\d+", yourString)
['1.3', '5.49', '1.3']
>>>
```

Then to convert to floats

```
>>> [float(x) for x in re.findall("\d+\.\d+", yourString)]
[1.3, 5.49, 1.3]
>>>
```