# In Python 2.7: How can I split a number from a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, split

My strings are something like that:

```
str1 = "3,5 of 5 stars"
str2 = "4 of 5 stars"
```

I want to extract the first number of each string.

Something like that:

```
str1 = 3,5
str2 = 4
```

The Problem is that the numbers are in two formats (int and float)

I hope you guys can help me

Thanks for your help

Comment: You use comma for floats? `str1 = 3,5` would translate in a tuple in Python not a float.. Will the generall format\pattern by `str = "X of Y stars"`?

Comment: do your strings always start with the number?

Comment: `.split(" of ")[0]`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I suspect this is a localisation issue - a lot of countries use a comma as the decimal mark

Comment: @MSeifert yes they start always with a number (e.g. 3 of.., 3,5 of ..)

Comment: @asongtoruin Fair enough but Python uses `.` dot. So in Python again 3,5 is **not** what you get when dividing 7 with 2 but rather `(3, 5)`; a tuple of two integers

Comment: Thanks Wiktor Stribiżew your solution works fine :)

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I know and agree with you - just trying to help highlight where the confusion may have arisen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a space before the `"of"`, you can use (*avoids regex*):

```
>>> print [item.split()[0] for item in [str1, str2]]
['3,5', '4']
```

Comment: Why does there have to be a space after the `"of"`? You probably mean before

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "3 o 4 k 5"

for char in string:
    entry = ""
    try:
        entry = int(char)
    except:
        continue
    if entry != "":
        print entry
        break
```

Here's the explanation. The `string` holds the string. As the `for` loop begins, `char` is set to the first character in the string. The `for` loop attempts to convert the character into an integer. If it is successful, it means that it is the character is a number. In that case, it is the first number to be found, so it is outputted and the loop stops.

If the conversion fails, it will output an error (thus the `except` part) but since we are using `try/except`, the loop will skip to its next character immediately. The `for` loop will continue until a number has been found or there are no numbers in the string.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your string format is - `X of Y stars`

You can extract X in this way.

```
>>> my_str = "3,5 of 5 stars"
>>> my_str.strip().split(' ')[0]
'3,5'
```

Let's say you want to convert `3,5` to float to do some math on it then you first replace `,` with `.` and then wrap around `float(...)`.

```
>>> float(my_str.strip().split(' ')[0].replace(',','.'))
3.5
```

Comment: you can replace the `,` with a `.`

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern of strings is always "X of Y stars" you can do the following:

```
str1 = "3,5 of 5 stars"
str2 = "4 of 5 stars"

lst = [str1, str2, ...]
nums = [float(x.split(' of ')[0].replace(',','.')) for x in lst]
print(nums)  # prints [3.5, 4.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

To match numbers and floats (using the `,` delimiter) in a string you could use the `re` module:

```
>>> re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\,\d+|\d+", "5,5 of 5 stars")
['5,5', '5']

>>> re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\,\d+|\d+", "5,5 of 5 stars")[0]
'5,5'

>>> re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\,\d+|\d+", "4 of 5 stars")[0]
'4'
```

I've used the regex from [this StackOverflow answer (from @miku)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4703409/5393381) but modified it to use `,` as delimiter instead of `.`.