# how to sep col as given char length in pandas?

Tags: pandas

How to seperate dataframe as follows:

```
   yr   mon  day      Tmax  Tmin   pcp
  2013   4  22        5.09-10.92   0.0                         
  2013   4  23        2.77 -9.63   0.5                         
  2013   4  24        0.28 -9.90   9.9                         
  2013   4  25        0.76 -6.70  12.2                         
  2013   4  26       -0.35 -9.48   0.0                         
  2013   4  27        7.22-10.47   0.0                         
  2013   4  28        4.19-10.78   0.0
```

you see: there are no whitespaces between Tmax and Tmin in principle.  The max width of  Tmax and Tmin are 6 char-spaces. If less than 6 spaces , filled by whitespace. I want to read it to `df` and seperate each columns.
seperate columns as given char length?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(filename)
```

Comment: This function is what I want.

Comment: @Cobin, glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) [floats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4703409/2901002) and `ints`, solution works if all data are in one column which is selected by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
pat="(\d+)\s*(\d+)\s*(\d+)\s*([-+]?\d+\.\d+|\d+)\s*([-+]?\d+\.\d+|\d+)\s*([-+]?\d+\.\d+|\d+)"
df1 = df.iloc[:, 0].str.extract(pat, expand=True)
df1.columns = ['year', 'mont','day','Tmax','Tmin','pcp']
print (df1)
   year mont day   Tmax    Tmin   pcp
0  2013    4  22   5.09  -10.92   0.0
1  2013    4  23   2.77   -9.63   0.5
2  2013    4  24   0.28   -9.90   9.9
3  2013    4  25   0.76   -6.70  12.2
4  2013    4  26  -0.35   -9.48   0.0
5  2013    4  27   7.22  -10.47   0.0
6  2013    4  28   4.19  -10.78   0.0
```

Another solution is use [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) and specify `colspecs`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""yr  mon  day       Tmax  Tmin   pcp
  2013   4  22        5.09-10.92   0.0                         
  2013   4  23        2.77 -9.63   0.5                         
  2013   4  24        0.28 -9.90   9.9                         
  2013   4  25        0.76 -6.70  12.2                         
  2013   4  26       -0.35 -9.48   0.0                         
  2013   4  27        7.22-10.47   0.0                         
  2013   4  28        4.19-10.78   0.0  """
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'

names=['year', 'mont','day','Tmax','Tmin','pcp']
colspecs = [(0, 6), (9, 10), (12, 14), (21, 26),(26,32),(34,38)]
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(temp),colspecs=colspecs, names=names, header=0)
print (df)
   year  mont  day  Tmax   Tmin   pcp
0  2013     4   22  5.09 -10.92   0.0
1  2013     4   23  2.77  -9.63   0.5
2  2013     4   24  0.28  -9.90   9.9
3  2013     4   25  0.76  -6.70  12.2
4  2013     4   26 -0.35  -9.48   0.0
5  2013     4   27  7.22 -10.47   0.0
6  2013     4   28  4.19 -10.78   0.0
```

Comment: Thx. I think the `colspecs` should be desgined in pandas

Comment: Yes, sure. [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#files-with-fixed-width-columns)