# How to remove tailing alphabet from dataframe column

Tags: python, regex, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe :

`A            B
 10.1        33.3
 11.2        44.2s
 12.3        11.3s
 14.2s       *
 15.4s       nan`

i want output as

`A            B
 10.1        33.3
 11.2        44.2
 12.3        11.3
 14.2          0
 15.4         0`

How do I remove these tailing alphabets 
I have tried this code

```
1st approch:
```

`bulb_temp_df['A'].str.extract('(\d)').astype(float)
    bulb_temp_df['B'].str.extract('(\d)').astype(float)`

2nd approch:

`bulb_temp_df['A'] = 
   bulb_temp_df['A'].astype(str)
   bulb_temp_df['A'] = 
   bulb_temp_df['A'].map(lambda x: x.rstrip('aAbBcC'))`

These are not working. They are not removing the tailing s from the columns.

Comment: I still havent found the solution for this tried doing this                                                              `bulb_temp_df[cols]=bulb_temp_df[cols].apply(lambda x:x.str.extract('(\d+\.\d+)',expand=False)
                                                      .astype(float)
                                                      .fillna(0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract [floats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4703409/2901002) first and for replace `NaN`s to `0` add [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html).

Solution is in [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for process multiple columns.

```
cols = ['A','B']

#if mixed values - numeric with strings
bulb_temp_df[cols]=bulb_temp_df[cols].astype(str)

bulb_temp_df[cols]=bulb_temp_df[cols].apply(lambda x:x.str.extract('(\d+\.\d+)',expand=False)
                                                      .astype(float)
                                                      .fillna(0))
      A     B
0  10.1  33.3
1  11.2  44.2
2  12.3  11.3
3  14.2   0.0
4  15.4   0.0
```

Comment: It return `NaN`, so function `fillna(0)` replace it. Thank you for accepting. You can upvote too - click to small triangle above `0` above accepting mark. Thanks.

Comment: sorry for confusion it is removing the 's' from the digit but the numbers which does not have alphabet it is making them 0. can you please rectify on this

Comment: Check answer, use `bulb_temp_df[cols]=bulb_temp_df[cols].astype(str)`

Comment: If i have some negative values in the column then it is not consodering those values those values are vanished . so itried this          `'(\-\d+\.\d+)'` but then it will not consider positive values what to do in this case.  I came acroos negative value and it is failing

Comment: I think you can use `'([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)'`, or omit + like `'([-]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)'`