# how to replace non-numeric or decimal in string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with values in degrees with the degree sign.

```
42.9377º
42.9368º
42.9359º
42.9259º
42.9341º
```

The digit 0 should replace the degree symbol

I tried using regex or str.replace but I can't figure out the exact unicode character.

The source xls has it as `º`

the error shows it as an obelus `÷`

printing the dataframe shows it as `?`

the exact position of the degree sign may vary, depending on rounding of the decimals, so I can't replace using exact string position.

Comment: You can use `ord(c)` to check what unicode number it has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['a'] = df['a'].str.replace('º', '0')
print (df)
          a
0  42.93770
1  42.93680
2  42.93590
3  42.92590
4  42.93410

#check hex format of char
print ("{:02x}".format(ord('º')))
ba

df['a'] = df['a'].str.replace(u'\xba', '0')
print (df)
          a
0  42.93770
1  42.93680
2  42.93590
3  42.92590
4  42.93410
```

Solution with [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) [floats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4703409/2901002).

```
df['a'] = df['a'].str.extract('(\d+\.\d+)', expand=False) + '0'
print (df)
          a
0  42.93770
1  42.93680
2  42.93590
3  42.92590
4  42.93410
```

Or if all last values are `º` is possible use [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
df['a'] = df['a'].str[:-1] + '0'
print (df)
          a
0  42.93770
1  42.93680
2  42.93590
3  42.92590
4  42.93410
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that it's always the last character you could remove that character and append a "0".

```
s = "42.9259º"

s = s[:-1]+"0"

print(s) # 42.92590
```