# Less ugly yet reliable way to find this floating-point value embedded within a string without padding?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

The following python returns the CPU temperature of my Raspberry Pi running Raspian 8.0 jessie:

```
import commands
err, msg = commands.getstatusoutput('vcgencmd measure_temp')
if not err:
   print msg
```

returns `"temp=47.2'C"` with a standard single quote instead of the degrees symbol.

This gives me the temperature as a float and so I have something that works.

```
print float(msg.split('=')[1].split("'")[0])
```

returns the float `47.2`

**Question:** But I wonder if there is a better, or more pythonic, or at least less hackish-looking way to do this?

**note:** I don't know how the OS builds the string, but the number could be variable in length, be > 100C or even have a minus sign, or possibly even have the trailing zero suppressed. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=+liquid+nitrogen

I have *heard* of regex but I don't normally do much with strings and have never tried to use it.

Comment: Can't you just use `float(msg[5:-2])`? The text always starts with `temp=` and ends with `'C`, right?

Comment: "[I] have never tried to use it." Well now is a good moment to try! there are some simple tutorials online. Regex is one of the best ways to find something in a string

Comment: @Aran-Fey I don't know the rules that the OS uses to build the string. It might zero-supress, and the temperature can have more or less digits, and be negative, so, no that won't work.

Comment: Regex could work with something like `re.sub(r".*=([0-9.]+)'.*", r'\1', "temp=47.3'C")` but I don't know if it's really necessary. It looks less hackish though.

Comment: @LioraHaydont considering my previous comment (which I'll put into the question in a second) do you know that regex will indeed do this?

Comment: The only assumptions I made are that the text starts with 5 useless characters (like `temp=`) and ends with 2 useless characters (like `'C`). Zero-padded or negative numbers are supported as long as those two assumptions are correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract a floating number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703390/how-to-extract-a-floating-number-from-a-string)

Comment: @Aran-Fey okay, (it's 3AM here I missed that) but I don't yet know if there could be other warnings or characters appended, so I can't guarantee there will always be exactly two characters after the float.

Comment: I don't see how the [link provided](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=+liquid+nitrogen) is relevant to the note which precedes it.

Comment: hey it's @uhoh from space! anyhow, heads-up that `commands` has been deprecated since 2.6, replaced by `subprocess`.

Comment: @tedder42 indeed! You are welcome to add an updated answer here if you are so inclined. I will try to do it at some point, but haven't been 2to3 qualified yet so it's better if someone who knows what they're doing does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution with regex, if you're interested:

```
import re

msg = "temp=47.2'C"
m = re.search(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', msg)
print(float(m.group()))  # 47.2
```

Comment: This does not look as scary as the other answers in the possible-dup link! Let me give it a quick try with some other possible messages.

Comment: Yes this is better as it reliably returns a single float even if I add other floats to `msg`. I will read more about `.search()` rather than `.findall()` and also `.group()`. Not only does it solve my problem, but it is clean, concise, and educational! I am no longer afraid of regex! woohoo! Normally I would not accept so quickly, I'll check back again later for more answers, but this seems concise and yet robust for my purposes.