# Pandas Dataframe: Extract numerical values (including decimals) from string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe consisting of a column of strings. I want to extract the numerical numbers of these strings. However, some of the values are in metres, and some in kilometres. How do i detect that there is a "m" or "km" beside the number, standardize the units then extract the numbers to a new column?

```
details                 numbers
Distance                350m
Longest straight        860m
Top speed               305km
Full throttle           61 per cent
```

Desired output:

```
details                 numbers
Distance                350
Longest straight        860
Top speed               305000
Full throttle           61
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
m = df['numbers'].str.contains('\d+km')
df['numbers'] = df['numbers'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
df.loc[m, 'numbers'] *= 1000 

print (df)
            details  numbers
0          Distance      350
1  Longest straight      860
2         Top speed   305000
3     Full throttle       61
```

Explanation:

1. Get mask for `km` values by [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)
2. Extract integer values and cast to `int` by [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)
3. Correct `km` values by multiple

EDIT: For extract `float`s values change regex in `extract` by [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4703409/2901002), also last cast to `float`s:

```
print (df)
            details      numbers
0          Distance        1.7km
1  Longest straight       860.8m
2         Top speed        305km
3     Full throttle  61 per cent

m =  df['numbers'].str.contains('\d+km')
df['numbers'] = df['numbers'].str.extract('(\d*\.\d+|\d+)', expand=False).astype(float)
df.loc[m, 'numbers'] *= 1000 
print (df)
            details   numbers
0          Distance    1700.0
1  Longest straight     860.8
2         Top speed  305000.0
3     Full throttle      61.0
```

Comment: Hey @jezrael, thanks! What if the km value contains a decimal? eg(1.7 km)? How do i change this regex expression: '\d+km'? To "\d+(?:\.\d+)+km"?

Comment: @doyz - Glad can help! Be free upvote solution too. Thanks. :)

Comment: This did not work for my columns which are strings that look like: ` Life-Stage Group Arsenic Boron (mg/d) Calcium (mg/d) Chromium Copper (μg/d)  \
0         <= 3.0 y   nan g         3 mg        2500 mg    nan g       1000 μg   
1         <= 8.0 y   nan g         6 mg        2500 mg    nan g       3000 μg