# Extract the last number in a dataframe with strings in Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, extract

I have dataframe from `pandas`. I am not sure how to start extracting the information.

The data in the column is like this:

```
->Company A 100->Company B 60->Company C 80-> Company D
->Company A 100->Company B 53.1->Company C 82.2->Company D 100-> Company G
->Company A 100->Company B 23-> Company D
```

etc...

The information of the companies are not important, only the last number in each item.

I want to extract the number before the last `->` and paste it into another column.

For example, extract `80`, `100`, and `23`, respectively.

```
80
100
23
```

I have this

```
import re
text = '->Company A 100->Company B 60->Company C 80-> Company D'
re.findall(r'\d+', text)[-1]
```

which gives the right output `'80'`

But when I do it for a `df`

```
re.findall(r'\d+', df['ColumnName'])[-1]
```

I get: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following if you want the last number of the string:

```
df['num'] = df['text'].str[::-1].str.extract('(\d+)')
df['num'] = df['num'].str[::-1]
df

           text                                         num
0   -> Company A 100->Company B 60->Company C 80->...   80
1   -> Company A 100->Company B 53.1->Company C 82...   100
2   -> Company A 100->Company B 23-> Company D          23
```

You can also try this if you only want the number before the last '->':

```
df['num'] = df['text'].str.split('->').str[-2].str.extract('(\d+)')

           text                                         num
0   -> Company A 100->Company B 60->Company C 80->...   80
1   -> Company A 100->Company B 53.1->Company C 82...   100
2   -> Company A 100->Company B 23-> Company D          23
```

If you want float numbers too before the last '->':

```
df['text'].str.split('->').str[-2].str.extract('(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')
```

The change is in the regex

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Is it possible to include those numbers with decimals too?

Comment: Thanks that worked. Is it difficult to extract all numbers before `->` (with decimals) into new columns as well? Or should I create a new post? :)

Comment: Ok, that is good. No worries, thanks for all the effort so far! Much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for asking. is it added now?

Answer (score 3):

Use [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4703409) for get floats or integers with [`findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) and get last values by indexing:

```
df['num'] = df['col'].str.findall(r'([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)').str[-1]
print (df)


                                                 col  num
0  -> Company A 100->Company B 60->Company C 80->...   80
1  -> Company A 100->Company B 53.1->Company C 82...  100
2         -> Company A 100->Company B 23-> Company D   23
```