# How does the below code work for sum of integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the question where i need to find the sum of elements in the given numArray for .

But i am unable to get the desired output i want.

```
numArray = map(int, input().split()) 

sum_integer = 0
#write your logic to add these 4 numbers here

print(sum_integer) # Print the sum
```

My solution for that is

```
for i in range(len(numArray):
   sum_integer=sum_integer+numArray[i]
```

What is wrong with my solution? And i cannot change the way the input is taken.

Comment: don't loop though `range(4)`, loop through `numArray`

Comment: OR `sum(map(int, input().split())`

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted. This is a legitimate question. The only thing that is missing is the error and traceback.

Comment: Do you get a SyntaxError or a TypeError? Your code as shown will not work at all.

Comment: "TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable " This the error i am getting

Comment: Note that whoever wrote that exercise is misleading you. ``numArray`` is not an array/list - it is an iterator.

Comment: Can you tell me what should i do then? and if you can also possibly tell me what is an iterator.I am new to programming

Comment: @Sathwik iterator, as opposed to a list, does not hold all the data in memory at any given moment. Rather it lets you *iterate* over it, fetching each element one by one and only occupying "one slot" in memory each time. This feature gives a lot of power for different scenarios. read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703390/how-to-extract-a-floating-number-from-a-string)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `map(int, input().split())` returns a map object which is an iterator, not a list. To illustrate, your code would work if you converted it to a list.

```
numArray = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

As the comments have point out, there are other, better ways to go about it. Changing the `for` loop to

```
for i in numArray:
    sum_integer += i
```

is a better solution, and doesn't force you to enter exactly 4 numbers. The other suggestion in the comments, to simply use

```
print(sum(map(int, input().split())))
```

which does all the steps in one line is far more concise.