# Robust regex to match all characters until a floating point number

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

I need a robust regex that will match all characters until a float.

I have a dict of strings with strings looking like the following mock example:

```
    'some string 1 some more 2.1 even more 9.2 caracala,domitian2.3'
...
```

I need a robust regex to substring each string only on the floats, so the end result will look like this:

```
{
  'some string 1 some more': '2.1'
  'even more': '9.2'
  'caracala,domitian': '2.3'
}
```

I'll use a for loop with python re to get the end result but **I need a robust regex that will match all characters until a float.**

I have tried: `[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+` but it selects numbers as well

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: There's a great website for this, https://regex101.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract a floating number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703390/how-to-extract-a-floating-number-from-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `re.findall` might get you the result you want:

```
inp = "some string 1 some more 2.1 even more 9.2 caracala,domitian2.3"
matches = re.findall(r'(.*?)\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*', inp)
print(matches)

[('some string 1 some more', '2.1'), ('even more', '9.2'), ('caracala,domitian', '2.3')]
```

Explanation of regex:

```
(.*?)       match all content up the first
\s*         optional space, which is followed by
(\d+\.\d+)  a floating point number
```

Note that we capture the leading content and float in separate capture groups, which then appear separately in the resulting list.