# how to split a string by number of decimal points?

Tags: python, regex, string

Let's say I have a line in a text file `output.dat` like this

```
in kB   16829.38785 17132.36275-14415.58515    72.67157   123.80624    17.02385
```

How can I split this string to 6 float objects, each contains 5 decimal points?

For now I am using the split by default (space).

```
import numpy as np

for line in open('output.dat'):
    if line.find('in kB  ') != -1:
        stress = -np.array([float(a) for a in line.split()[2:]])
```

And as expected, this returns an error like this

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '17132.36275-14415.58515'
```

Edit: I want to make one thing clear, "-" means negative number, not just a connector. So I want to keep that after the split. The whole problem is exactly caused by when there is a negative result, the "-" occupies a space.

Comment: Are those values always 5 characters after decimal ?

Comment: Do you always consider `17132.36275-14415.58515` as two floats seperated by `-` for every line?

Comment: you cannot convert 123-456 to float. try to use regex search and get the string between `.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract a floating number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703390/how-to-extract-a-floating-number-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.findall` will do this.

The exact regular expression used will depend on exactly how you want the string to be interpreted. In the following example, it is not insisting on exactly 5 decimal places; also the `-` is part of the number (remove the `-?` if that is not the case).

```
import re

s = "in kB   16829.38785 17132.36275-14415.58515    72.67157   123.80624    17.02385"

print([float(x) for x in re.findall("-?\d+\.\d+", s)])
```

gives

```
[16829.38785, 17132.36275, -14415.58515, 72.67157, 123.80624, 17.02385]
```

Note that in the output, the value will not be exactly correct to the number of decimal places shown; this is an ordinary feature of floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, `\d+` any digit `\d{5,}` Matches at least 5 consecutive digits.

```
import re

txt = "16829.38785 17132.36275-14415.58515    72.67157   123.80624    17.02385"

[float(v) for v in re.findall("(-?\d+.\d{5,})", txt)]
```

output,

```
[16829.38785, 17132.36275, -14415.58515, 72.67157, 123.80624, 17.02385]
```

Comment: Hi. I want to keep "-" because that is a negative number

Comment: @cobra1994, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can either split multiple times:

```
values = line.split()[2:]
values = [float(x) for xs in values for x in xs.split('-')]
stress = -np.array(values)
```

Or you can use a regex:

```
import re

values = re.findall(r"[\d,\.]+", line)
stress = -np.array([float(x) for x in values])
```

I'm ignoring the '5 decimals' bit, but if you need to ignore any decimals beyond the 5th, you should definitely use a regex:

```
values = re.findall(r"[\d]+\.\d{5}", line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"[\-]{0,1}[0-9]*\.[0-9]{5}"

test_str = "16829.38785 17132.36275-14415.58515    72.67157   123.80624    17.02385"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

```
Match 1 was found at 0-11: 16829.38785
Match 2 was found at 12-23: 17132.36275
Match 3 was found at 23-35: -14415.58515
Match 4 was found at 39-47: 72.67157
Match 5 was found at 50-59: 123.80624
Match 6 was found at 63-71: 17.02385
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but "-" means a negative number, not just a connector. So I want to keep that after the split.

Comment: @cobra1994 updated, please check