# Extract Floats from a String - Regex - Python

Tags: python, regex, floating-point

Hi I would like to be able to extract **just** floats from a string

```
str = "Test string 1.234 0.155.1 5.67799350,-2.654657
```

Outcome should be

```
[1.234, 5.67799350, -2.654657]
```

I was using `[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+` but it detect the 0.155.1 which I don't want.

```
import re
floats = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", str)
```

Thanks for your reading.

Comment: but `0.155` is a float, yes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
[-+]?\b(?<!\d\.)\d+\.\d+\b(?!\.\d)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/M1mVsa/1)

Alternative to match floats without integer part (`.59`) and when glued to word characters (`_4.567`):

```
[-+]?(?<!\d\.)(?<!\d)\d*\.\d+(?!\.?\d)
```

See [another proof](https://regex101.com/r/M1mVsa/2)

It matches an optional plus/minus, one or more digit, dot, one or more digits, wrapped with word boundaries and not in between digit-dot and dot-digit.

**Python**:

```
import re 
text = 'Test string 1.234 0.155.1 5.67799350,-2.654657'
print([float(i) for i in re.findall(r"[-+]?\b(?<!\d\.)\d+\.\d+\b(?!\.\d)", text)])
```

Result:

```
[1.234, 5.6779935, -2.654657]
```

Comment: doez not macher `_1.234` or `.234`

Comment: @Edward I added an alternative that should fix this.

Comment: `[-+]?(?<!\d\.)(?<!\d)\d*\.\d+(?!\.?\d)` matches `.<9.76>.` and `<.976>.` shouldn't match either,

Comment: @Edward  I am afraid you are contradicting yourself, if `1.234` and `.234`  must be a match, `.976` and `9.76` must be a match, too.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you found your code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4703409/9758194)? Either way, maybe a negative lookbehind and lookahead will work for you and create a more solid pattern?

```
(?<!\.)[-+]?\b\d+\.\d+(?!\.)\b
```

See the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LSAAdo/2)

---

*Pattern breakdown:*

- `(?<!\.)` - Negative lookbehind for a literal dot.
- `[-+]?` - Optional plus or minus sing.
- `\b` - Word-boundary.
- `\d+\.\d+` - One or more digits, a literal dot and again one or more digits.
- `(?!\.)` - Negative lookahead for a literal dot.
- `\b` - Word-boundary.

[image]

---

*Python sample code:*

```
import re 
str = 'Test string 1.234 0.155.1 5.67799350,-2.654657'
lst = [float(i) for i in re.findall(r'(?<!\.)[-+]?\b\d+\.\d+(?!\.)\b', str)]
print(lst)
```

Result >>

```
[1.234, 5.6779935, -2.654657]
```

Answer (score 0):

try  `(?<![.\d])[-+]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?![.\d])`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/32eB3z/1)