# Extracting floating number from string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working on google maps, which is retuning distance in string like `1,230.6 km`. From this I wanted to extract the floating number `1230.6`.

Below is what I tried

```
var t = '1,234.04 km';
var a = t.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') // 123404

parseFloat(t) // 1
```

How do I fix this with Regex ? Please guide

Comment: Try `+'1,234.04 km'.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')`

Comment: `parseFloat('1,234.04 km'.split(",").join(""))` you can remove the comma if the string always looks like your example

Comment: duplicate of [12064575](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703390/how-to-extract-a-floating-number-from-a-string)

Comment: FYI: Most languages return a [different result](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html) because they use a comma for their decimal seperator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `.` in your Regex:

```js
var t = '1,234.04 km';
var a = t.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '') // 1234.04

parseFloat(a) // 1234.04
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following,

```js
var t = '1,234.04 km';
var a = t.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')
    
console.log(parseFloat(a) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let t = '1,234.04 km'.split(',').join('');
var regex = /[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g;
var floats = t.match(regex).map(function(v) { return parseFloat(v); });
console.log(+floats);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.