# Leave in column only digits and decimal point

Tags: regex, pandas

I have a column with a string containing letter with a number. The number is sometimes with and sometimes without a decimal point.
I want to convert the number to float.
example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'colA': ['q7.8', 'g5.3', '4.5r', 'john7']})
```

The updated column should contain: `7.8, 5.3, 4.5 7.0`.

There are no systemic rules for the number of letters and their location.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming only one number is in each cell we can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) then [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) to convert to `float`:

```
df['colA'] = df['colA'].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)').astype('float')
```

There are many regex available at [How to extract a floating number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703390/how-to-extract-a-floating-number-from-a-string) if additional considerations like exponentionation or positive/negative are needed like:

```
df['colA'] = df['colA'].str.extract(
    r'([-+]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?)'
).astype('float')
```

*Note with this approach `extract` needs exactly 1 capturing group.

`df`:

```
   colA
0   7.8
1   5.3
2   4.5
3   7.0
```