# How to Extract Numeric Values from Strings in Database

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': 'A B C D'.split(),
                   'result': ['.50', 'text 10', 'text 0.20', '<0.75']})

print(df)

  name     result
0    A        .50
1    B    text 10
2    C  text 0.20
3    D      <0.75
```

I need to extract the numeric values (float, integer or any digits). I'm trying the following script but not getting the desired output with too many `NaN` values:

```
df['result'] = df['result'].astype(str)
df['result'].str.extract(r'(/\d+\.\d+/)')
```

**Desired output**

```
  name     result
0    A       .50
1    B       10
2    C      0.20
3    D      0.75
```

What would be the smartest way of doing it? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract a floating number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703390/how-to-extract-a-floating-number-from-a-string)

Comment: Hi @JacobBotha, sorry it doesn't Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different pattern:

```
df['result2'] = df['result'].str.extract(r'([0-9.+-]+)')
print(df)

# Output
  name     result result2
0    A        .50     .50
1    B    text 10      10
2    C  text 0.20    0.20
3    D      <0.75    0.75
```

Comment: Hi @Corralien, it kinda works. Thank you. However, I'm getting about 38 `.` counts, which aren't in the original data. Also, it's not letting me convert to `float` values.
```.              38
.100            2
.110            4
.120            5
.130            3
```

Comment: I removed the conversion. What do you want to do with this kind of values?

Comment: I am curious how 38 `.` came. I can remove them using ```['result'] != '.'``` though.

Comment: Can you update your post with this data. Without formatting, I don't understand the structure.